# Alternative to side scrolling table for an infinite list of X-Axis checkbox items

Tags: tables, checkboxes, scrolling, alternatives, checklist

I have a problem in which there is a table that does not have a predefined amount of columns or rows. i.e., for both the X and Y axis there is no limit. This invites a high probability of the user encountering a side scroll interface.

The table has been created so that user can make selections by column and row.

i.e., for Row A, I select Col A, Col B, Col X.

With both X and Y axis variable, and the table serving the purpose of a multi-option check list, has anyone experienced an interface alternative?

I am thinking about card selections. I.E., a user selects a card and then checks options vertically rather than horizontally. I think this will be a more pleasant user experience, but then the user is no longer exposed to every row at once, which can be helpful for understanding the dynamics between the rows.

Any other ideas?

Excel example which aligns with current (problematic) interface:
[image]

Topic with solution **A** (i.e, the card select solution):
[image]

Comment: In which ways does your app behave like Microsoft's Excel? Maybe pulling some functionality from there can help you out.

Also, is there a way you can illustrate your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Added some pictures. Let me know if that is enough context.

Comment: One more question: What is a user trying to accomplish with this table? (If there's multiple uses here, could you explain each use case?)

Comment: For each topic they need to select 0, 1 or many options.

Lets say, the topics are people, the options are different types of sushi.

Problem: horizontal scrolling most likely will happen with the current interface as there is any number of types of sushi.

Comment: This question was asked few months ago. Did you already build your own solution? If not, what I believe is missing is a sense of understanding why people are doing this. What is it that they are trying to accomplish? Only then can this question be truly answered.

Comment: It's just your typical "Bus Matrix" type view, where you have an Object and then attributes you may want to correspond to that object. Or maybe I am saying that wrong. Think of a User Role, then a list of potential permissions for that role. As the system expands, more and more attributes can be added to a role, and additional roles may be added, as well.

Comment: The problem to solve? I have a limitless amount of types of a thing that has a potentially limitless amount of attributes. Was the problem solved? Yes. Does the solution suck? Also, yes.